# Automate conversion of numbers to latex

Tags: python, latex

**Background:**
I have a script which produces a set of numbers in python and then writes them to a `.tex` file (which is subsequently read in by latex as the table). The `.tex` will typically look like

`\begin{tabular}{lcc}
x & 1e2 & 0.1
\end{tabular}`

**Problem:**
I'd like to know if there exists a library which can 'texify' a python float. By this I mean take the python float and return a string with a valid latex representation.

For example, if the function was called `texify` then it would operate as follows:

`In [1]: x = 1e2
In [2]: print texify(x)
'$1 \times 10^{2}$'`

I have already built an ad-hoc version of this, but there are always edge cases. So, I want to ask the community of you know of any such preexisting solutions?

Comment: **texify** has to produce scientific notation?

Comment: Does it have to work ONLY with `AeB`, or are there other use cases as well? Would you be able to show us more examples?

Comment: There is also the `siunitx` latex package which uses tex/latex to format python-style floating point numbers, i.e. `\num{1.1e11}` will look the same as `1.1 \times 10^{11}` in the final document.